# android studio: layout preview diffrent from actual device layout

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I just installed android studio and try to run the default project with a button on my real device and this is my I'm seeing:

[image]

The text is in the right side instead the left, the envelop icon on the left instead the right, and the button just wrap himself on the screen.

the xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.hello.tsvi.myapp.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:background="#1bb0ce">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: re move these lines code   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Comment: Where is the FAB in your xml??

Comment: what result you want?

Comment: The problem is that all the elements in the picture not where they should be

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.hello.tsvi.myapp.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:background="#1bb0ce">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your envelop Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```